# How to determine if my program is 'on the company domain'

Tags: c++, windows, networking, active-directory

I'm trying to determine if my service is currently connected to the company domain or not.

I tried

```
BOOL bResult = LogonUser(m_userName, m_domainStr, m_password, LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, &userHandle);
```

but it returns true if the credentials are good.

I'm guessing that Windows is checking the cached credentials and determining that they are good.

I suppose I could use a Ping, but a Firewall would stop that too.

Is there a nice, clean way to determine if a computer is on the 'corporate network' (e.g. can connect to the AD).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for the availability of the DCs SYSVOL share.

I would query DNS for a list of DCs, then Loop through the DCs until I can Access the share.  If I can, I'm online.  If I can't, I'm offline.

If on the Company Lan, but the DCs are unavailable, you might just as well be offline...